# Getting 'bad_weak_ptr' error

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I am trying to pass one shared pointer from the `QTGUI` class to the `Client` class, and keep getting `bad weak ptr` errors. I have read that I can't assign an `shared_from_this()` directly in a constructor, because the pointer is not ready at that point.

I have therefore created a `getptr` function that returns the pointer of the object, in order to assign it later to the client in a further call. However it does not seem to work neither.

What am I missing here? Thank you very much in advance.

**qtgui.hpp**

```
#ifndef QTGUI_H
#define QTGUI_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileSystemWatcher>

#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class Client;

namespace Ui {
class QTGUI;
}

class QTGUI : public QMainWindow, public boost::enable_shared_from_this<QTGUI>
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QTGUI(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QTGUI();

    void start();
    boost::shared_ptr<QTGUI> getptr();

    /* Signals */
    typedef boost::signals2::signal
        <void (const char* ipaddress, const char* port)> start_connect;
    typedef start_connect::slot_type start_connect_st;

    boost::signals2::connection start_connect_ui(const start_connect_st& slot);

private slots:
private:
    Ui::QTGUI *ui;

    boost::shared_ptr<Client> client_;

    start_connect sc_signal;
};

#endif // QTGUI_H
```

**qtgui.cpp**

```
#include "qtgui.h"
#include "ui_qtgui.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include <QFileDialog>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include "../client/client.hpp"


#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

QTGUI::QTGUI(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::QTGUI),
    connected_(false),
    client_(new Client)
{


    start();
}

boost::shared_ptr< QTGUI > QTGUI::getptr()
{
    return shared_from_this();
}

void QTGUI::start()
{

    client_->addui(getptr());
    client_->get_con_status(boost::bind(&QTGUI::connection_status, this, 
_1));
}

boost::signals2::connection QTGUI::start_connect_ui(const start_connect_st& 
slot)
{
    return sc_signal.connect(slot);
}
```

**client.hpp**

```
#ifndef CLIENT_HPP
#define CLIENT_HPP

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

#include "../common/message.hpp"

class QTGUI;

class Client : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Client>
{
public:
    Client(/*boost::shared_ptr<QTGUI> ui*/);

    void addui(boost::shared_ptr<QTGUI> ptr);


    /* Signals */
    typedef boost::signals2::signal<void (bool status)> connect_status;
    typedef connect_status::slot_type connect_status_st;

    boost::signals2::connection get_con_status(const connect_status_st& slot);

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<QTGUI> ui_;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread_;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service_;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket_;

    connect_status cs_sig;
};

#endif//  client.hpp
```

**client.cpp**

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/protect.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#include <cstdio> /* sprintf */

#include "client.hpp"
#include "../common/commands.hpp"
#include "../common/kinotify.hpp"
#include "../gui/qtgui.h"

#include <functional> 
#include <unistd.h>

Client::Client(/*boost::shared_ptr<QTGUI> ui*/):
//ui_(ui),
io_service_(new boost::asio::io_service),
work_(new boost::asio::io_service::work(*io_service_)),
connected_(false)
{
    start();
}
void Client::addui(boost::shared_ptr< QTGUI > ptr)
{
    ui_ = ptr;
    std::cout << "Connecting..." << std::endl;
    ui_->start_connect_ui(boost::bind(&Client::post_connect, 
                                      shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
}


void Client::start()
{
    if(thread_)
        return;

    std::cout << "Creating new thread bruh" << std::endl;
    thread_.reset(new boost::thread(
        boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, io_service_)
    ));
    std::cout << "start Thread ID [" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << 
    "]" << std::endl;
}

void Client::stop()
{
    if(!thread_)
        return;

    std::cout << "Ending" << std::endl;
    socket_->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
    socket_->close();
    io_service_->stop();
    thread_->join();
    io_service_->reset();
    thread_.reset();
}

boost::signals2::connection Client::get_con_status(const connect_status_st& 
slot)
{
    return cs_sig.connect(slot);
}
```

---

**EDIT**: add main.cpp

```
#include "qtgui.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTGUI w;
    w.start();
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have read that I can't assign an shared_from_this() directly in a constructor, because the pointer is not ready at that point.

The is true, you cannot use `shared_from_this()` until the object is fully constructed. It's only at that point that the underlying `weak_ptr` is assigned. The restriction isn't just *directly* from the constructor - you're still calling `shared_from_this` before `QTGUI` s completely constructed. The fact that you're using a function to retrieve it, from a different function, is immaterial.

Just call `start()` externally to the class after you create it. That will just work.

---

Side note: `getptr()` is useless. Just use `shared_from_this()` directly.

Comment: Another note: for `shared_from_this` to work, there __must__ be `shared_ptr` already owning the object, as weak references will threat object as invalid otherwise. This is where restriction on constructor comes from: it is owning `shared_ptr`, which properly sets weak reference and it cannot do its work until object is completely constructed.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I tried to do call the `start` function from the `main` —I included the code in the question— but it still gives me the same error. I saw with the debugger that it gives me the error in the exact point in which I call `shared_from_this` in the start function. Why is this?

Comment: @StrikeTeam Because `w` isn't a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Barry I am accepting your answer because I consider the question answered, but I have a little complication. The `QTGUI w;` can't be a `shared_ptr` because otherwise the application gives me an `Assertion px !=0` failed. I guess it is because of `Qt`s internal management or something. Is there a way I can pass the class' pointer to the `Client` somehow?

Comment: @Strike I don't know what that assertion is.

Comment: @Barry It is part of `/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:648: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = QTGUI; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = QTGUI*]: Assertion px != 0' failed.`

Comment: @Strike Huh? Just make it a `shared_ptr`: `shared_ptr<QTGUI> w = make_shared<QTGUI>();`

Comment: @Barry Oh my goodness. I can't believe I missed that. I was looking everywhere to see what was happening and I forgot to check the most basic thing. Thank you again.

Comment: "immaterial"? Did you mean "irrelevant"? (last word of your first paragraph)

Comment: @AlexisWilke Those two words are synonymous.